# Is there a way to warn about unused data members of a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, attributes, compiler-warnings

There are situations where all the members of a struct are expected to be used in a function.

Often times, more data gets added to the struct, but it does not get handled in the corresponding function.  This leads to unused data, that we would like to be warned about.  Is there some kind of compiler attribute that can do this?

Here is an example, of what I was hoping it would look like:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{
  int a=0;
  int b=0;
  int c=0;
};

void handle_all_data(Foo f __attribute__((use_all)) );

int main(){

  Foo f;
  handle_all_data(f);
}

void handle_all_data(Foo f){

  std::cout << f.a << '\n';
  std::cout << f.b << '\n';
}

//warning: f.c is not used anywhere in "handle_all_data"
```

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: A better question (IMHO) would be to ask for warning about *uninitialized* members in a structure. By initializing all members you are in fact "using" all the members. Also how would the compiler truly know if all members are "used" or not? What if you call a function from another translation unit and passes the structure, then it can't know if any members are "used" or not.

Comment: The other issue is that this warning would clearly be present in the *caller* rather than the API code, which means you are weakly enforcing a contract that should be done at the API level.